# How to replace values after every nth row

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a sample of my data:

[image: Data Sample]

Below is the desired result:

[image: Desired Result]

In this example, I have shown you that I am looking for something that ignores the value in the 2nd row and every value in every 5th row after that (row 7, 12, 17 etc...) but, for the rows in between I am looking to replace the values with the value 0.

In my scenario, I am looking for this method where the value in row 2 is ignored and then every 58th row value is ignored (row 60, 118 etc...), but replacing the values in between with the value 0.

Below is some of the code I used myself, but this didn't get me anywhere as the replace function looks for specific values and I couldn't find anything that was more suited to this problem.

```
Sub Replace()

Dim OriginalText As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim aws As Worksheet

Set aws = ActiveSheet
For Each cel In aws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    OriginalText = Replace(OriginalText, "100", "0")
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Do those number (100, 200, 300 etc.) exist, or you placed them only to emphasize the zero placed between them?

Comment: @FaneDuru used the emphasise the zero placed between them, the solution cant be a simple replace if, then 0

Comment: Not exactly... The idea was to  not count on that numbers and use them to place zero when they change. Please, try the code I pasted. It should be very fast, even for large ranges, using an array and making all processing in memoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next fast code, even for a large range. It uses an array, all happening in memory and drops the processed array content at once:

```
Sub ReplaceToZero()
Dim aws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long, k As Long, boolEnough As Boolean
Const zeroNo As Long = 5
Const colLett As String = "A" 'use here the necessary column letter

Set aws = ActiveSheet
lastR = aws.Range(colLett & aws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

arr = aws.Range(colLett & "2:" & colLett & lastR).Value2
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If k > 0 And k <= 5 Then
        arr(i, 1) = 0
        If k = zeroNo - 1 Then boolEnough = True
    End If
    If boolEnough Then
        k = 0: boolEnough = False
    Else
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i

'drop the processed array content at once:
aws.Range(colLett  & 2).Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: I have over 300,000 records and this took just over one second, thank you for the code sir

Answer (score 2):

[image: EXAMPLE - SHEETA is the codename of the sheet]

```
'in Module1
Public Sub Replace(ws As Worksheet, columnLetter As String, _
           startFromRow As Long, stepRows As Long)
    Dim r As Range, toRow As Long, cc As Long
    Set r = ws.Range(columnLetter & startFromRow)
    toRow = r.End(xlDown).Row
    'Debug.Print toRow
    For cc = 0 To toRow
       If cc Mod stepRows <> 0 Then
          r.Offset(cc, 0).Value = "0"
       End If
    Next

End Sub

'in sheet's module
Sub example()
    'Call Replace(SHEETA, "A", 2, 5)
    Call Replace(Me, "A", 2, 5)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, this replaces every 5th value, starting from row 2, giving me (0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 200, 200 etc)

Comment: It's easy to do the opposite... as I fixed it using the Mod

Answer (score 0):

Use of a counter variable can be a simple approach.`enter code here`

```
Sub Replace()
' Works on active Sheet
co = 0 ' Start on
For Each c In Range("A2:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
co = co + 1
If co = 58 Then
' Ignore replacement of the value, and reset counter
co = 0
Else
c.Value = 0
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: getting the error Compile Error:  "For Each can only iterate over a collection object or an array"

Comment: Simplified the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim MyData As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last non blank row
MyData = Range("A2:A" & LR).Value 'save original data into array
Range("A2:A" & LR).Value = 0 'make ALL cells equal to 0

'now loop original array in steps of 5 and return original data
'row 2 is index 1 in array, row 7 is index 6 and so on...

For i = 2 To LR Step 5
    Range("A" & i).Value = MyData(i - 1, 1)
Next i

Erase MyData 'clean variable

End Sub
```

[image]